# Laravel 4 BadMethodCallException upon calling a method of a model

Tags: php, laravel-4

I created a User class in Laravel application as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
...
public function hasAnyRoles()
{
     return true;
}
```

The function there is simplified to always return true for the purposes of this example. I pretty much followed this tutorial here to create this class: http://alexsears.com/article/adding-roles-to-laravel-users. I created a controller next as follows:

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
  public function welcomeAction()
  {
     $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
     $result = $user->hasAnyRoles();
     return Response::make("Result: ".$result);
  }
}
```

I'm able to successfully login to the system, routes are working as intended, the variable $user is correctly initialized and I can get all the information out of it (username, id, email, etc.) but once I call the `$user->hasAnyRoles()` method I get:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasAnyRoles()
```

If I comment out the respective line in the controller it all works but I cannot call any method of that model without getting that error. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: p.s. once you solve the problem - you can squash your whole controller into one line of code `return Response::make("Result: ".Auth::user()->hasAnyRoles());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stupid as it is, it turns out that the application was reading the User class from a different file. I had a User_backup.php copied in the same directory just in case and this was the file that the class was read from so any changes to User.php were disregarded. I had to remove the backup file and do a composer update in order to get it all working correctly..